# Compatibility of SQL server native client 10.0 with Windows XP

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-xp, compatibility, odbc-sql-server-driver

Is the driver "SQL server native client 10.0" compatible with Windows XP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - XP SP3 or later supports the v10.0 native client.

See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=228de03f-3b5a-428a-923f-58a033d316e1&DisplayLang=en#SystemRequirements

Comment: I am not able to install "Native Client" driver from the same link (sqlncli.msi) on a XP machine. Is there any prerequisites for sqlncli.msi?

Comment: @Sajo Mathew - Other than XP SP3, I don't think there are any other prerequisites. I've been able to install the 10 and 11 clients on Windows XP VMs.

Comment: Could you please send the exact link to download sqlncli.msi for XP SP3 that you used. Is it http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123718&clcid=0x409 . I am getting the following error when I am using that link - "SQL server 2008 native client set up interrupted". I am getting the same error on XP SP3 and server 2003 SP2

Comment: @Sajo Mathew - I used the same link you've provided above. If you're having problems, try using the SQL 2005 Express installer and do a custom install to install only the client tools

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Now the issue is resolved. I am able to use SQL server 2008 and SQL server native client 10.0 from Windows XP